# How to access wheel collider in a child object in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, wheelcollider, child-objects

In Unity, my player gameObject has 4 wheels and all of them contain wheel colliders. I want to get the rpm of these.

I write this code, but at line 33 it is throwing index/argument out of bound exception, which means the index it's trying to access with 'GetChild(i)' is not accessible.
line 33 is

```
 wColliders[i] = gameObject.transform.GetChild(i).gameObject.GetComponent<WheelCollider>();
```

My player has 5 child objects and 4 of them have a wheel collider. how to solve it?

````
```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
 {

    //[SerializeField] private float speed = 10f;
    [SerializeField] private float speed;
    [SerializeField] private float rpm;
    private float totalRpm;
    [SerializeField] private float horsePower;
    [SerializeField] private float turnSpeed;
     public float horizontalInput;
     public float forwardInput;

    [SerializeField] private GameObject centerOfMass;
    [SerializeField] TextMeshProUGUI speedometerText;
    [SerializeField] TextMeshProUGUI rpmText;
    
    List<WheelCollider> wColliders;
    private Rigidbody playerRb;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        playerRb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

        playerRb.centerOfMass = centerOfMass.transform.position;

        wColliders = new List<WheelCollider>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            wColliders[i] = gameObject.transform.GetChild(i).gameObject.GetComponent<WheelCollider>();
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        forwardInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        playerRb.AddRelativeForce(Vector3.forward * horsePower * forwardInput);
       
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, Time.deltaTime * turnSpeed * horizontalInput);

        speed = playerRb.velocity.magnitude;
        speed = Mathf.RoundToInt(speed);
        speedometerText.SetText("Speed: " + speed);

        for(int i = 0; i < wColliders.Count; i++)
        {
            totalRpm += wColliders[i].rpm;
        }

        rpm = Mathf.Round(totalRpm / wColliders.Count);

        rpmText.SetText("RPM: " + rpm);
    }
}
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the [`IndexOutOfBoundsException`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940979/what-is-an-indexoutofrangeexception-argumentoutofrangeexception-and-how-do-i-f) not because Unity doesn't find the child but rather because you try to access/set

```
wColliders[i]
```

of an **empty** list. There are no items added yet so you can not access them via the index.

---

You would rather use [`List<T>.Add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.add)

```
for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    wColliders.Add(transform.GetChild(i).GetComponent<WheelCollider>());
}
```

---

Or actually rather simply use [`GetComponentsInChildren`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponentsInChildren.html)

```
wColliders = GetComponentsInChildren<WheelCollider>(true).ToList();
```

Comment: I see, I used list<> but I was trying to access it by the process of array[i]. Thanks for clearing the confusion

Comment: No that's not what I said. Your access both arrays and lists the same way via `theCollection[i]` .. your problem rather was that you never `Add` elements to the list so it is always empty and none of the `wColloders[i]` exists yet. If this answer solved your question please feel free to accept it (✔️)